# Fourier transform converges to zero $\mathcal{F}(f)(k)= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-ikx} dx \approx \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} f(x)e^{-ikx} dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

This question is due to the comment made on page 19 in the paragraph of the following lecture notes [click me](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/probability/lecturenotes/RandomWalks.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjGstz1w7bJAhUGqA4KHRVfC6sQFggFMAA&usg=AFQjCNFtdkN8LINptI7S_-k1_Z4joYIfdA) starting with

$\text{Standard Fourier theory shows that...}$

I have an even function $f \in L^1{[-\pi,\pi]}$ and want to take the Fourier transform of $f,$ i.e.

$$\mathcal{F}(f)(k)= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-ikx} dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(kx) f(x) dx.$$

Now, the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma implies that $\mathcal{F}(f)(k) \rightarrow 0$ for $|k| \rightarrow \infty.$

Does this in some sense imply that $$\mathcal{F}(f)(k) \approx \int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon} \cos(kx) f(x) dx$$ for $|k|$ large, i.e. that the support of the integrand is restricted to small$|x|$?

Somehow this seems reasonable, as increasing $k$ in the cosine (meaning we converge to zero) is the same as having high $|x|$. Thus the support of the integrand should be close to $|x|\approx 0.$ Of course this is not a rigorous argument at all, as it totally ignores $f$, but maybe you are aware of a similar result or can show something like this?

Of course this does not have to depend on the fact that $f$ has finite support and is even, but this is the setting in the lecture notes.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.